# Spark when union a lot of RDD throws stack overflow error

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

When I use "++" to combine a lot of RDDs, I got error stack over flow error.

Spark version 1.3.1
Environment: yarn-client.  --driver-memory 8G

The number of RDDs is more than 4000. Each RDD is read from a text file with size of 1 GB.

It is generated in this way

```
val collection = (for (
  path <- files
) yield sc.textFile(path)).reduce(_ union _)
```

It works fine when `files` has small size.
And there is the error

The error repeats itself. I guess it is a recursion function which is called too many time?

```
 Exception at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPartitions(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD$$anonfun$1.apply(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPartitions(UnionRDD.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
  .....
```

Comment: what's the size of your input data?

Comment: By default, Spark use memory only RDD serialization. You may want to try with a persist on disk option if it doesn't fit.

Comment: @eliasah question updated. But how does size of input matter?

Comment: @C4stor could you give some code?

Comment: val collection = (for (
  path <- files
) yield sc.textFile(path)).reduce(_ union _).persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK) ?

Comment: so actually you are trying to fit 4TB into the default worker memory of spark? how is he supposed to work on it?

Comment: @C4stor I changed the code. It doesn't work. Still the same error

Comment: you don't have enough executor memory!!

Comment: @eliasah, then it should be Out of memory error. The spark throughs the error even before the job started. (namely nothing is shown in the web UI ). I have used 10 times smaller memory to process 10 times smaller file numbers. Everything works fine.

Comment: A stack overflow error can come from variables being too big to allocate on the stack. So it's memory related!

Comment: @eliasah java objects are stored in heap memory not stack memory.

Comment: I agree and both are located within the limit of the JVM.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `SparkContext.union(...)` instead to union many RDDs at once.

You don't want to do it one at a time like that since RDD.union() creates a new step in the lineage (an extra set of stack frames on any computation) for each RDD, whereas SparkContext.union() makes it all at once. This will insure not getting a stack-overflow error.

Comment: I totally agree but I was just wondering if it insures not getting a stack-overflow error?

Comment: Yes, since `RDD.union()` creates a new step in the lineage (an extra set of stack frames on any computation) for each RDD, whereas `SparkContext.union()` makes it all at once.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit your answer adding the information you mentioned in your comment. I believe it completes the answer.

Comment: Is there a similar method to join multiple data frames at once.I am facing a similar issue where I am joining one dataframe at a time instead of joining all at once.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952740/joining-huge-list-of-data-frames-causes-stack-overflow-error

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when union RDD one by one can get into a series of very long recursive function calls.
In this case we need to increase JVM stack memory.
In spark with option `--driver-java-options "-Xss 100M"`, driver jvm stack memory is configured to 100M.

Sean Owen's solution also solves the problem in more elegant way.