# How to create collection of RDDs out of RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an `RDD[String]`, `wordRDD`. I also have a function that creates an RDD[String] from a string/word. I would like to create a new RDD **for each string** in `wordRDD`. Here are my attempts:

1) Failed because Spark does not support nested RDDs:

```
var newRDD = wordRDD.map( word => {
  // execute myFunction()
  (new MyClass(word)).myFunction()
})
```

2) Failed (possibly due to scope issue?):

```
var newRDD = sc.parallelize(new Array[String](0))
val wordArray = wordRDD.collect
for (w <- wordArray){
  newRDD = sc.union(newRDD,(new MyClass(w)).myFunction())
}
```

My ideal result would look like:

```
// input RDD (wordRDD)
wordRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ('apple','banana','orange'...)

// myFunction behavior
new MyClass('apple').myFunction(): RDD[String] = ('pple','aple'...'appl')

// after executing myFunction() on each word in wordRDD:
newRDD: RDD[String] = ('pple','aple',...,'anana','bnana','baana',...)
```

I found a relevant question here: [Spark when union a lot of RDD throws stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522564/spark-when-union-a-lot-of-rdd-throws-stack-overflow-error), but it didn't address my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to get `RDD[String]` as you desire.

```
var allWords = wordRDD.flatMap { word => 
  (new MyClass(word)).myFunction().collect()
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to run in parallel? Everything which happens within `wordRDD.map` is executed on the cluster. Thus, the inner `collect` has to trigger a new Spark job from within a running job. I suspect that it won't run distributedly.

Comment: He could also alter the function to return arrays instead of RDDs, but the question didn't specify the actual function.

Comment: But his description says that he has a function, I assumes it's `myFunction` that creates a `RDD[String]` from a string/word.

Comment: Yes it does. Your answer tells him to change `myFunction` to return something different. Without knowing how complicated the function is it is hard to say if the calculations done in it are distributed or not. If collecting a data set means that all previous calculations done are no longer distributed, then nothing would be distributed.

Comment: Have you ever tried running your code? It is basically not possible calling `collect` from within another `RDD`. How do you imagine this should be realized? The `collect` method will trigger the job execution and return the results as a `Seq` to your driver node. But the `flatMap` operation is part of your job which is executed distributedly. How shall the `collect` method then be executed? Moreover, the `SparkContext` which is necessary to generate new `RDDs` is simply not serializable. Thus, it is not possible to ship it with your UDF.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ship it, but I have run the code that I originally posted. It worked. @JacekLaskowski made my code more compact, but I assume it still works.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create a `RDD` from within another `RDD`.

However, it is possible to rewrite your function `myFunction: String => RDD[String]`, which generates all words from the input where one letter is removed, into another function `modifiedFunction: String => Seq[String]` such that it can be used from within an RDD. That way, it will also be executed in parallel on your cluster. Having the `modifiedFunction` you can obtain the final `RDD` with all words by simply calling `wordRDD.flatMap(modifiedFunction)`.

The crucial point is to use `flatMap` (to `map` and `flatten` the transformations):

```scala
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Test").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

  val input = sc.parallelize(Seq("apple", "ananas", "banana"))

  // RDD("pple", "aple", ..., "nanas", ..., "anana", "bnana", ...)
  val result = input.flatMap(modifiedFunction) 
}

def modifiedFunction(word: String): Seq[String] = {
  word.indices map {
    index => word.substring(0, index) + word.substring(index+1)
  }
}
```